# Express $\frac{\Gamma \bigg(\frac{\nu+k}{2}\bigg) }{\Gamma (\frac{\nu}{2})(\nu\pi)^{\frac{k}{2}}}$ as a beta function

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions, gamma-function, beta-function

If
$$\frac{\Gamma \bigg(\frac{\nu+1}{2}\bigg) }{\Gamma (\frac{\nu}{2})\sqrt{\pi}}= \frac{\Gamma \bigg(\frac{\nu+1}{2}\bigg) }{\Gamma (\frac{\nu}{2})\Gamma (\frac{1}{2})}= \frac{1}{B \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\nu}{2} \right)},$$
by way of the property $\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) = \int_0^\infty x^{-1/2}e^{-x} \, dx = 2\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2} \, du = \sqrt{\pi},$

What is $$\frac{\Gamma \bigg(\frac{\nu+k}{2}\bigg) }{\Gamma (\frac{\nu}{2})(\nu\pi)^{\frac{k}{2}}}$$ equal to in terms of the beta function?

Comment: Hint: $B(x,y) = \frac{{\Gamma (x)\Gamma (y)}}{{\Gamma (x + y)}}$.

Comment: I don't even know how to find $\Gamma(y)$ first. If $\sqrt{\pi}= \Gamma(\frac{1}{2})$, what is $(\nu \pi)^\frac{k}{2}=?$

Comment: Hint: $x=\nu/2$, $x+y=(\nu+k)/2$, so $y=$? You cannot get rid of $(\nu \pi)^{k/2}$ in the general case.

Comment: $y=\frac{k}{2}$, but $\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})$ doesn't simplify to anything? so you're saying the expression in the question can no longer be simplified? Or is the answer $$\frac{1}{B \left(\frac{\nu}{2}, \frac{k}{2} \right)}?$$

Comment: Your expression cannot be written as a single beta function. But is the beta simpler than the gamma? Your original expression is already quite simple, why do you want to re-write it no matter what? What is yor aim?